# Where to ask for website recommendations about where I can post my code samples?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm looking for a website that allows programmers to share their source code, but not in a formal context like (Git/SVN). Handy pieces of source code, but not like a public clipboard (like jsffiddle).

If I ask this on stackoverflow or programmers, then I think it'll get closed. Where to ask?

EDIT:

I'm looking to create a knowledge base of things I've learned, and other people as well. I could just start my own Wiki, but it would get no traffic and not really worth doing.

Comment: You're right about it being closed on SO. And I don't think it would be appropriate for any site within the network.

Comment: Ask somewhere other than the Stack Exchange network of sites.

Comment: hahaha... I give up. :)

Comment: Chat would be the better (and perhaps the only) option within Stack Exchange. Broad recommendation questions in general don't really work with the Q&A format, Stack Exchange was build with questions about specific problems in mind. [slant.co](http://www.slant.co/) might be worth checking out, the site is build _specifically_ for broad recommendation questions, and its format seems to be working.

Comment: @Yannis very true, I did know that list requests weren't allowed but forgot. I'll head over to chat and give that a try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Overflow is a knowledge base -- a knowledge base on Questions and Answers.  If you have code that's important to you that you'd like to share, there are ways to do this, but it's tough and takes practice to get it right.

As I mentioned, Stack Overflow is for Q&A. Therefore, all content posted must be in Q&A format. Stack Exchange has a feature where one may self-answer a question, and there are instances where this feature has proved useful.

Here is a brief outline on how to get started:

- Your code likely solved a problem you were facing. Therefore, at one point, you most likely had a question of some sort. You could ask this question and then post your solution.
- But first, search, **search**, ***search*** to see if the question has already been asked and answered. If you're just posting duplicates of problems already solved, then your post is just noise. The community will close it, and I'd hate to see you spend time drafting a question and answer only to see your efforts tossed aside. Remember, always search first!
- Make sure the problem is easily digestable.  Questions about how to create a fadeout effect without jQuery are more likely to fit the format than questions about how to build a fully-fledged complete chat solution.  Questions that are too broad will be closed as such.
- Be sure to write the question as if you're two people. When you post the question, role play. Play the role of someone who has a problem he/she cannot solve, who has done some research and tried something. Then play the role of an answerer and answer the post.  When reading the question and answer, we shouldn't be able to tell you're the same person without looking at your username.
- Make sure the posts are self-contained. Don't just link to your Github repository. In fact, if you have to link to a third-party resource at all, then the problem is most likely too broad for Stack Overflow. While you *could* link to your Github repository, the community may look at this unfavorably and treat your contributions as spam. It's best to leave that material out until you learn more about how self-answering works and have a few *successful* self-answers under your belt.

Remember, self-answering can be done, but it's hard -- harder than posting normal, everyday questions that *aren't* intended for self answer.  If you try this, and it doesn't work as intended, use the feedback from the community to learn and improve, and stay calm in the face of negative feedback. Also, remember that you must be solving problems that *haven't already been solved on Stack Overflow*; otherwise, they'll be closed as duplicates. Hope this helps!